# Automatic telemarketing canceller

Tags: android, voice

I want to be able to intercept/answer an incoming call on a per-cid basis and, when I find appropriate, stream a local audio file as the answer to the call - i.e over the speech channel of an ordinary voice call. This should ideally be done in background mode, either when I'm connected in an ongoing voice call or just silently, without blocking other incoming calls, when I'm not.

Reason for this is that I want to create The Ultimate Black List App, that answers my phone when telemarketing people calls me (or any other individual that I simply do not want to communicate with) and dumps an audio file of my own choice (preferably selected based in incoming CID) into their ear.

Any ideas on how to do this, anyone?

Comment: This site is more focused on answering code based questions.  Try it out and see where you get stuck.

Comment: It is also currently impossible to add audio to phonecalls if I remember correctly.

Comment: duplicate of [Play an audio clip onto an ongoing call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900564/play-an-audio-clip-onto-an-ongoing-call) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268964/stream-audio-to-a-phone-call-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492457/android-phone-call-audio-stream-via-wlan and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319949/need-to-play-audio-to-the-caller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452595/playing-an-pre-recorded-audio-file-to-somebody-over-a-call and many others.

Comment: Hi, @sqrfv: Just wanted to see if it is worth the effort trying at all.... As for now, I'm redirecting some known numbers to the voicemail directly, but I'd just like to be a little bit more, ... shall we say blunt to some people.

Thanks anyway, you saved me alot of time, guys!